# Spring Security, JSF - loadUserByUsername username is null

Tags: java, spring, security, jsf

I have one problem in loadUserByUsername() Spring Security, because the username when go to loadUserByUsername() is empty. I checked other post, but the problem persist.
continuation my progress...

1- security.xml:

```
<form-login 
login-page="/login.xhtml" 
login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
username-parameter="usuario" 
password-parameter="password"    
/>
...
<authentication-manager>
 <authentication-provider user-service-ref="springSecurityUserContext" /> 
</authentication-manager>
```

2- SpringSecurityUserContext.java

```
@Component
public class SpringSecurityUserContext implements UserDetailsService{
 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String arg0) 
  throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    // arg0 is empty
     ...
}
```

3- LoginManagedBean.java

```
@Component
public class LoginManagedBean {

    private String usuario;
    private String password;

    public String login() throws ServletException, IOException{
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = ((ServletRequest) context.getRequest())
                .getRequestDispatcher("/j_spring_security_check");

// attributes username y password arrive well
        dispatcher.forward((ServletRequest) context.getRequest(),
                (ServletResponse) context.getResponse());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

        return null;
    }
```

4- login.xhtml

```
    <h:form id="loginForm" prependId="false" method="post" >
      usuario: <p:inputText id="username" name="username" 
value="#{loginManagedBean.usuario}"/>
      password: <p:inputText id="password" name="password" 
        value="#{loginManagedBean.password}"/>
      <p:commandButton type="submit" ajax="false" value="ingresar"  
        action="#{loginManagedBean.login}" />
```

good day!. :)

Comment: Spring security expects, by default, `j_username` and `j_password`. Why don't you just create a simple login form that directly submits to the `j_spring_security_check`? Creating the JSF Managed bean feels like overkill.

Comment: in theory it should work as I expected, but 
apparently the variables must be named j_username and j_password are necessary. thank you very much!!

Comment: You can also configure the `username` and `password` fields within the `<form-login/>` element. Either way should work.